# Почему файл который превращен в строку не редактируеться как строка?

Tags: c#

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему файл который превращен в строку не редактируеться как строка? Совсем нечего не меняеться

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ffrgrgrthtr
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {string path = @"C:\MyTest2.txt";
    string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
    
  String modified = text.Insert(3, "dgdgdfg ");
  Console.WriteLine(text);
  Console.ReadLine();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String modified = text.Insert(3, "dgdgdfg ");
Console.WriteLine(modified);
                  ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Этот метод не работает.

Comment: Я понял, я сделал глупую ошибку.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.